# Whenever I try to create an Instance of a specific class the whole app crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, infinite-loop

My code seems to crash due to an infinite loop, but I can't find the error.
Could someone help me out and look over the code?

**Here is my controller:**

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        let x = Float(location.x)
        let y = Float(location.y)
        let newTouch = Touch(latitude: x,longitude: y)
        TouchService().addTouch(touch: newTouch, grid: _grid)
    }
}
```

**And my model:**

```
import Foundation

class Touch {

    var _lat: Float
    var _long: Float
    var _startingPoint: Touch

    init(latitude lat: Float, longitude long: Float){
        self._lat = lat
        self._long = long
        self._startingPoint = Touch(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }
}
```

I guess there is something wrong with the way I am using the init() function.

Kind regards and thanks in advance, 
Chris

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift. Properties with leading underscores are *uncool*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Problem**

Your initializer creates an infinite loop.

```
//Touch(latitude: lat, longitude: long) calls the initializer again.
//Since you are inside the initializer, it creates an infinite loop.  
self._startingPoint = Touch(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
```

Comment that out and you'll see.

### **Solution**

Create a separate class or struct for your values (composition).

```
class AngularLocation {
    var _lat: Float
    var _long: Float
```

and

```
class Touch {
    var destination: AngularLocation
    var startingPoint: AngularLocation
```

Tweak that to your needs.

Comment: Why do I have to remove the "self." tag?

Comment: @Fukuan `self.` in an initializer is only required if the corresponding argument is the exact same name.  Otherwise, it's **typically** a stylistic choice.  Also, your app was failing because you were calling the initializer within the initializer, not because of `self.`

Comment: Ah, I get it. I removed both and now everything works just fine. 
Thank you for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code is working

```
class Touch {

var _lat: Float
var _long: Float
var _startingPoint: Touch

init(latitude lat: Float, longitude long: Float){
    self._lat = lat
    self._long = long
    self._startingPoint = Touch(latitude: lat, longitude: long) // It invokes recursively your Touch class with no end, so it causes infinite loop
   }
}
```

**Solution**

You have to create different class for `StartingPoint`.